# Can the speed of the wind influence the speed of sound propagated in it?

Tags: kinematics, velocity

The question came up with a exercise (Page 5, exercise (vi) of Pratice Exercise 1.1) from the book Physics Galaxy Volume 1 Ed. 1, Ashish Arora. The question proposes the following:

> Two junglemen are standing at the two opposite banks of a river of width $l$ facing each other. One of the starts beating a drum and sound reaches to the other one after time $t_{1}$ he starts. Then second one starts beating the drum and now first onde hear the sound after time $t_{2}$. Calculate the velocity of sound relative to air and the velocity of wind. If it is blowing from first bank to the ohter bank at right angle to the river flow.

As far as I know the speed of sound depends exclusively on the medium. In this case, approaching the air with the ideal gas model, the equation that would obtain the speed of sound would be $v_{s}=\sqrt{\dfrac{\gamma P}{\rho}}$. To say that the speed of the air mass influences the speed of sound would be the same as saying that the speed of an ambulance causes the speed of the siren sound to be the speed of the air plus the speed of the moving ambulance, and so I know it's not. The solution to the question in the book itself considers that the speed of the air influences the speed of sound of the drum beat. Is this true or does the question have a physical conceptual error?

Comment: The speed of sound is always $\sqrt{\gamma P/\rho}$ **relative to the air**. So if the air is moving at some velocity $v$ relative to you the speed of sound you'll measure is $\sqrt{\gamma P/\rho} + v$.

Comment: @JohnRennie nailed it.  I, being the troublemaker,  suggest also solving for windspeed reaching relativistic values :-)

Comment: I will note that the question is worded a bit confusingly.  The speed of sound *relative to the wind* as measured by a tool moving with the wind remains unchanged.  The time of arrival to the observer on the ground depends on the wind speed and direction.